# Windows Phone 7 UserExtenedProperties opinion…

Tags: windows-phone-7

I was thinking of a way to some how connect my phone user base to my site user base. Right now if an item gets added to the site via the phone the userId is generic and the site displays it as SmartPhoneUser. I was thinking it might be cool to display the unique phone id by using the UserExtenedProperties, however, after reading [Nick Harris's blog](http://www.nickharris.net/tag/userextendedproperties/) about it I'm thinking it may not be a good idea as I don't want users to think I'm up to anything nefarious.

So I'm wondering if there are any suggestions out there on how to accomplish this task. Right now my site uses the JanRain module that allows multiple logins from other sites (Facebook, Yahoo, Google etc.).  I'm letting users log in to their own accounts and using the information from those sites to populate my user table.  I'm not sure if WP7 has something similar I can use.

Any thoughts on how I can accomplish what I want to do without using the ExtendedProperties?

Comment: The way I would accomplish something similar it to create a unique guid/DateTimeStamp the first time the app starts and save it in Isolated storage. Using this key should suffice.

Comment: would I then save that ID in iso storage for later usage?

Comment: Yes. Everytime the app starts you can retrieve the ID and use it to identify the usage from a specific device. Like a browser cookie.

Comment: OK I'll try that.  Put it as an answer and I'll vote it up and if it works I'll put it as the answer.

Comment: sure. Let me know if you need any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can accomplish something similar by creating a unique guid/DateTimeStamp KEY the first time the app launches and stored it in Isolated storage.

Reusing the same KEY by reading it from Isolated Storage should work.

[N.B. : Anybody with other ideas please do suggest/comment/contribute. Tx.]

Comment: This appears to work.  It is kind of a long number, but I guess that is what it makes it unique.  Thanks for the suggestion!